# How to plot dot labeled data?

Tags: gnuplot

I'd like to turn a file like:

```
Name  X  Y
a     1  2
b     4  1
s     3  3
```

in a X-Y graphic with the X-Y dots labeled with Name.

How can I do it? I think this can be done with gnuplot, but I wasn't able to do it yet.

Comment: I'm fairly certain gnuplot can do it too, but I'm no master, sorry. :(

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981589/use-text-column-from-data-file-as-points-label-in-gnuplot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put labels at a specified offset from the points using the following gnuplot command:

```
echo "plot 'file.dat' using 2:3 pt 2 notitle, '' using 2:3:1 with labels offset 0.5,0.5 notitle;" | gnuplot -persist
```

NB: works only if gnuplot has been compiled with --enable-datastrings (thanks to DaveParillo for the clarification)

Comment: +1 nice avoidance of a separate label file.  I've always done it that way and didn't think there was any other way.

Comment: FYI: If this example doesn't work for someone - the `labels` style is available only if gnuplot is built with configuration  option --enable-datastrings

Comment: If not available, the error looks like "Not enough columns for this style"? I guess it's not available here where I am :(

Answer (score 2):

<s>Gnu plot can't do this alone.  I doesn't know what to do with the text.</s>  If your data exists in a file named file.dat, then:

```
perl -ane 'print "set label \"($F[0])\" at $F[1],$F[2]\n"' file.dat > label.plt
```

will produce a label file you can use in gnuplot.  You can then produce a (very basic) plot like this:

```
gnuplot> load "label.plt"
gnuplot> plot 'file.dat' u 2:3
```

You can mess around with the label offset if you want.  For example,

```
"set label \"($F[0])\" at $F[1]+0.05,$F[2]+0.05\n"'
```

moves the labels out a bit, so that they are not right up against your points.