# How to plot data with lines and label in each point?

Tags: gnuplot

I have an archive "curva-l" with the data:

```
2.308E-05   5.397E-01     1.0E-09  
2.318E-05   5.224E-01     1.0E-08
2.426E-05   5.029E-01     1.0E-07 
4.012E-05   4.718E-01     1.0E-06
1.311E-04   4.155E-01     1.0E-05
3.751E-04   3.703E-01     1.0E-04
1.306E-03   3.197E-01     1.0E-03
```

The first column is the axis X, the second Y, and the third is the value of each point. I would like to plot this curve with lines and label each point with the their respective value.

[image: Like this one]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to plot dot labeled data?](https://superuser.com/questions/67228/how-to-plot-dot-labeled-data)

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the gnuplot version you have.
There are many example [[1](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/),[2](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/datastrings.html),...] you can start with. Take inspiration from the demos.

The style of the image you shown is `linepoints`, and you can plot the labels with the keyword `with label`.
You can print 2 times the same dataset, one with the linespoints, and the second with the labels.

Start with

```
plot "data.dat" w linespoint , '' with labels
```

and give it a look. After find the offset you prefer.
The following code

```
set xlabel "My X Axes"
set ylabel "My Y Axes"
plot "data.dat" with  linespoint lw 2 pt 11 \
   , ''        with labels center offset 3.4,.5 notitle
```

gives you this image

[image: Plot of the code]

In a second time you can modify the `xrange`, `yrange`... add logarithmic scale...

Answer (score 3):

Or in a single command:

```
< /tmp/dat awk '{print $1,$2,$2,$3}' | feedgnuplot --domain --style 0 'with lines' --style 1 'with labels' --rangesize 1 2 --set 'logscale x' --set 'logscale y'
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer: Explain what `feedgnuplot` is and what part of that command actually solves the asker’s problem.